# How to export class with static nested class in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In order to create nested static class i follow [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

```
class Album {
    label: Album.AlbumLabel;
}
namespace Album {
    export class AlbumLabel { }
}
```

However, I need to export class Album too. When I do

```
export class Album {
    label: Album.AlbumLabel;
}
namespace Album {
    export class AlbumLabel { }
}
```

I get `Individuals declarations in merged declaration 'Album' must be all exported or all local`. How to fix it?

Comment: `export namespace Album { ... }` ?

Comment: @jcalz Do you mean, that I don't need to do `export class Album` and I only should do `export namespace Album`?

Comment: Export both.  That's what "declarations must be all exported or all local" means.  Either export both of them or neither of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option one is to do as your told by the compiler and export both:

```
export class Album {
    label: Album.AlbumLabel;
}

export namespace Album {
    export class AlbumLabel { }
}
```

Option two is a shimmy variable, but you have a naming dilemma:

```
class Album {
    label: Album.AlbumLabel;
}

namespace Album {
    export class AlbumLabel { }
}

export const NameMe = Album;
```

The first option is a better choice (I reckon).

## Imports

If you want to import `AlbumLabel` directly, don't nest it. It's in a module already, so have the module export `Album` and `AlbumLabel`.

If you keep the nesting you have to use either:

```
import { Album } from './component.js';

const a = new Album.AlbumLabel();
```

Or introduce a local name:

```
import { Album } from './component.js';
const AlbumLabel = Album.AlbumLabel;

const a = new AlbumLabel();
```

Here's the example that allows `import { AlbumLabel } from './album';`

```
export class Album {
    label: AlbumLabel;
}

export class AlbumLabel { }
```

Comment: The answer was too long for a comment, so I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation.